# catkin_make fails on feature test macro

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ubuntu 13.10, ROS Hydro-Desktop-Full (built from source)]

I am getting an error I can't find a resolution to when using `catkin_make` for a project of mine.
For some reason, it fails on a line in a header file which turns `dispatch_release()`  on/off based on CLANG's `__has_feature(objc_arc)` feature test macro.

```
[100%] Building CXX object gwbrb/CMakeFiles/gwbrb_node.dir/src/gwbrb.cpp.o
In file included from /home/user/projects/gWRb/src/gwbrb/src/gwbrb.h:5:0,
                 from /home/user/projects/gWRb/src/gwbrb/src/gwbrb.cpp:16:
/home/user/projects/gswb/gwbw.h:110:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
                   ^
make[2]: *** [gwbrb/CMakeFiles/gwbrb_node.dir/src/gwbrb.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gwbrb/CMakeFiles/gwbrb_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Does catkin switch to Obj-c when it needs to, or do I have to tell it manually?  Can someone please assist with instructions?

Cheers,
Nap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155526/catkin_make-fails-on-feature-test-macro./) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin doesn't do anything specific for Obj-C, this is more likely to be a CMake behavior, but I don't know much about that.

A quick google search didn't turn up anything either. It looks like you are using GCC, and I believe that this is a CLANG specific feature (`__has_feature(...)`), maybe that is the root cause of the problem?

**Update:**

Adding these CMake options will ensure that clang is used for compilation, allowing that feature to work:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-04-21**:
@William, thnx.
It's definately a CLANG feature, and I was thinking that `catkin_make` ran clang by default.  So I've now added `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++` in my wrapper script, and it's getting past that error.  Cool.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-21**:
Ok, yeah catkin_make just does the normal cmake invocation, it doesn't set a compiler explicitly. Glad you got it working.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-04-22**:
@William, add the CMake switches I posted above to your post and I'll mark it as the answer.